# Angular & Firebase: Create new node

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to build same sctructure in Firebase. How can I create a new node `terriangen`, add `{key}` and set my object data?

```
-usernames  
 -{UID}    
  -mylibrary      
   -{key}    
  -terriangen       
   -{key}        
    type:mountain         
    name:1.png
```

My code:

```
const newObjRef = firebase.database()
              .ref('usernames')
              .child(userId)
              .child('mylibrary/')
              .push();
            newObjRef.set({
              type: terrainType,
              name: terrainName
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a multi-location update:

```
const newKey = firebase.database().ref().push.key;
const updates = { };
updates["mylibrary/"+key] = {
          type: terrainType,
          name: terrainName
        };
updates["terriangen/"+key] = {
          type: terrainType,
          name: terrainName
        };
firebase.database()
        .ref('usernames')
        .child(userId)
        .update(updates)
```

The biggest differences:

- We pre-generate the unique key, so that we can use it in both locations
- We move part of the path of the new data into the keys, so that we can perform a so-called multi-location update. This ensures none of the existing items in the `library` and `terriangen` nodes get overwritten.

Comment: Thanks for response. But I need just create a new node `terriangen` without updating another location. So, if I understood you correctly, I can use your approach without this part -  `updates["mylibrary/"+key]`. And my new node will be created, correct?